# How to translate encoding by ansi into unicode

Tags: python

When I use the CountVectorizer in sklearn, it needs the file encoding in unicode, but my data file is encoding in ansi.

I tried to change the encoding to unicode using notepad++, then I use readlines, it cannot read all the lines, instead it can only read the last line. After that, I tried to read the line into data file, and write them into the new file by using unicode, but I failed.

```
def merge_file():
    root_dir="d:\\workspace\\minibatchk-means\\data\\20_newsgroups\\"
    resname='resule_final.txt'
    if os.path.exists(resname):
        os.remove(resname)
    result = codecs.open(resname,'w','utf-8')
    num = 1
    for back_name in os.listdir(r'd:\\workspace\\minibatchk-means\\data\\20_newsgroups'):
        current_dir = root_dir + str(back_name)
        for filename in os.listdir(current_dir):
            print num ,":" ,str(filename)
            num = num+1
            path=current_dir + "\\" +str(filename)
            source=open(path,'r')
            line = source.readline()
            line = line.strip('\n')
            line = line.strip('\r')

            while line !="":
                line = unicode(line,"gbk")
                line = line.replace('\n',' ')
                line = line.replace('\r',' ')
                result.write(line + ' ')
                line = source.readline()
            else:
                print 'End file :'+ str(filename)
                result.write('\n')
                source.close()
    print 'End All.'
    result.close()
```

The error message is :UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: illegal multibyte sequence

Comment: First, we need to know if you use Python 3 or 2, these are very different when using unicode. Also for inspiration: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90100/convert-between-unicode-normalization-forms-on-the-unix-command-line

Comment: I use python 2.7

Comment: One idea is to *first* convert the whole file to unicode, as in the linked answers, with `uconv`. There are python examples too there.

Comment: thank you for your help,but i still cannot solve the problem...

Comment: Are you sure the input file is in GBK encoding? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK_(character_encoding) Can you convert it with uconv or iconv to UTF8 just to see? What did you try more!? Let us know your findings, or it's a guessing game ...

Comment: In notepad++ it shows the file is in ansi encoding. I haven't  tried to use uconv and iconv. Thanks your help, and now I find the way.

Answer (score 0):

Oh,I find the way.
First, use chardet to detect string encoding.
Second,use codecs to input or output to the file in the specific encoding.
Here is the code.

```
import chardet
import codecs
import os
root_dir="d:\\workspace\\minibatchk-means\\data\\20_newsgroups\\"
num = 1
failed = []
for back_name in os.listdir("d:\\workspace\\minibatchk-means\\data\\20_newsgroups"):
    current_dir = root_dir + str(back_name)
    for filename in os.listdir(current_dir):
       print num,":",str(filename)
       num=num+1
       path=current_dir+"\\"+str(filename)
       content = open(path,'r').read()
       source_encoding=chardet.detect(content)['encoding']
       if source_encoding == None:
           print '??' , filename
           failed.append(filename)
       elif source_encoding != 'utf-8':
           content=content.decode(source_encoding,'ignore')
           codecs.open(path,'w',encoding='utf-8').write(content)
print failed
```

Thanks for all your help.